# read the elements of a text in python

Tags: python, list, txt

I have a text file like this:

[image]

there is no separation mark.
When I use these lines of code, it returns nothing:

```
with open('input.txt','r') as f:
   contents = f.read()
   print(contents)
```

How can I save its elements in a python list or array?

Comment: The issue is with the formatting of your "input.txt" file. You could inspect it to see if it actually is a text file and that you can edit the numbers in notepad. There is nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `input_numbers.txt` looks as follows:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

To parse it as a list of ints, you can use the following approach:

```
import itertools
with open("input_numbers.txt", "r") as f:
    res = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list(map(int, x.split(" "))) for x in f))

print(res)
```

PS: Note that the question you asked is *How can I save its elements in a python list or array?*, not *how can I print it to screen* (despite what your code tries to do)

Answer (score 2):

```py
Array = []
with open('input.txt','r') as f:
   #contents = f.read()
   Array = f.readlines()
   print(contents)
```

Comment: This reads all the lines and each line is added to the array.

Comment: When I run it, the '\n' is added to every text element. I want an output array with pure numbers.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
    with open("./input.txt",'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

Data = pd.read_csv('input.txt')
My_list = []
for line in Data:
    My_list.append(line)

print(My_list)
```

Comment: This code returns just one element.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you want.

```
    with open("./input.txt",'r') as file:
        elements = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file]
    print(elements)
```